# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, syntax

Why do i receive a syntax error as such: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

I am using microsoft visual studio 2005 and sql server 2005

```
string strSql =
 "SELECT a.MCode, a.NameOfModule, a.Mod_Abbreviation, dt.ModuleCode,
  dt.Course, dt.Stage, dt.ModuleGrpFrom, dt.ModuleGrpTo, dt.GrpName,
  dt.GrpType, dt.StaffID, dt.AcadYear, dt.AcadSemester,
  dt.TotalHour, dt.WeeklyLectHr, dt.WeeklyPractHr, dt.WeeklyTutHr,
  dt.ModuleLeader, 0 AS TotalTeach, '' AS ModuleGroups, '' AS ML, 0 AS L, 0 AS P, 0 AS T, 1 AS NofGrp, '' AS TotalTeachUnit" +
 "FROM (SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT a.ModuleCode, a.Course, a.Stage, a.ModuleGrpFrom,
    a.ModuleGrpTo, a.GrpName, a.GrpType, a.StaffID, b.AcadYear,
    b.AcadSemester, b.TotalHour, b.WeeklyLectHr, b.WeeklyPractHr,
    b.WeeklyTutHr, b.ModuleLeader
   FROM ModuleStrGrp a 
   LEFT JOIN ModuleStr b ON a.AcadYear = b.AcadYear
    AND a.AcadSemester = b.AcadSemester
    AND a.Course = b.Course
    AND a.ModuleCode = b.ModuleCode) AS MSG 
   INNER JOIN Parameter Para ON MSG.Course = Para.Paracode2) AS dt 
  LEFT JOIN Module a ON dt.ModuleCode = a.MCode" +
 "WHERE dt.AcadYear LIKE AcadYear AND dt.AcadSemester LIKE AcadSemester 
   AND dt.Course LIKE Course AND dt.Stage LIKE Stage AND dt.StaffID LIKE Staff
   AND dt.SpecGrp LIKE Specialisation" +
 "ORDER BY dt.ModuleCode, dt.GrpType";
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Have you tried to test each assignment or do we have to do that for you?

Answer (score 10):

Missing spaces.
Your code is creating the string

```
"... , '' AS TotalTeachUnitFROM (SELECT * ..."
```

Same goes for the other lines, they need spaces between them.

Answer (score 5):

make `"FROM ...` as `" FROM ...`

right now it is `... AS TotalTeachUnitFROM ...`

Answer (score 4):

I won't answer your question, but I'll give you a strategy:

copy the contents of the strSql string to the clipboard, then to a query in SQL Management Studio, and run it there.

Then it will actually tell you which "AS" is causing the problem. Most likely it's a missing space or appostraphe or comma.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing spaces.

```
"...a ON dt.ModuleCode = a.MCode" +
"FROM (SELECT * FROM ..."
```

results in

```
"...a ON dt.ModuleCode = a.MCodeFROM (SELECT * FROM ..."
                                ^
                            space missing
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather use @ instead of +

```
string strSql = @"SELECT a.MCode, a.NameOfModule, a.Mod_Abbreviation, dt.ModuleCode, dt.Course, dt.Stage, dt.ModuleGrpFrom, dt.ModuleGrpTo, dt.GrpName, dt.GrpType, dt.StaffID, dt.AcadYear, dt.AcadSemester, dt.TotalHour, dt.WeeklyLectHr, dt.WeeklyPractHr, dt.WeeklyTutHr, dt.ModuleLeader, 0 AS TotalTeach, '' AS ModuleGroups, '' AS ML, 0 AS L, 0 AS P, 0 AS T, 1 AS NofGrp, '' AS TotalTeachUnit
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.ModuleCode, a.Course, a.Stage, a.ModuleGrpFrom, a.ModuleGrpTo, a.GrpName, a.GrpType, a.StaffID, b.AcadYear, b.AcadSemester, b.TotalHour, b.WeeklyLectHr, b.WeeklyPractHr, b.WeeklyTutHr, b.ModuleLeader FROM ModuleStrGrp a LEFT JOIN ModuleStr b ON a.AcadYear = b.AcadYear AND a.AcadSemester = b.AcadSemester AND a.Course = b.Course AND a.ModuleCode = b.ModuleCode) AS MSG INNER JOIN Parameter Para ON MSG.Course = Para.Paracode2) AS dt LEFT JOIN Module a ON dt.ModuleCode = a.MCode
WHERE dt.AcadYear LIKE AcadYear AND dt.AcadSemester LIKE AcadSemester AND dt.Course LIKE Course AND dt.Stage LIKE Stage AND dt.StaffID LIKE Staff AND dt.SpecGrp LIKE Specialisation
ORDER BY dt.ModuleCode, dt.GrpType";
```