# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' and 'AS'

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax

```
string sqlQueryString = " SELECT g.code AS GoodCode, g.name AS GoodName, " +
"msr.name AS MsrName, sm.min_quan AS KolMin, sm.max_quan AS KolMax, " +
"sm.quan AS KolNal, ord.prc AS EdPrice, s.name AS Sklad, m.name AS Mol, " +
"k.code AS KodDost, k.name AS NameDost " +
"FROM N_GOODS_{0} AS g INNER JOIN " +
"G_SMGS_{0} AS sm ON g.id = sm.good_id INNER JOIN " +
"N_KNTRS_{0} AS k ON g.id = k.id INNER JOIN " +
"N_PRC_LISTS_{0} AS pr ON g.id = pr.id INNER JOIN " +
"G_ORDD_{0} AS ord ON sm.smg_id = ord.smg_id INNER JOIN " +
"N_MOLS_{0} AS m ON sm.mol_id = m.id INNER JOIN " +
"N_STORS_{0} AS s ON sm.stor_id = s.id INNER JOIN " +
"N_MSRS_{0} AS msr ON g.id = m.id";
sqlQueryString = String.Format(sqlQueryString, dbLink.CurrentFirm.Id);

return " ( " + sqlQueryString + " ) AS t";
```

This is the string for an sql query, that I am trying to do in a piece of c# code. However I lost my whole day trying to make it work. This is the error that I get :

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Comment: We'll need to see the entire query that's being executed, rather than just this one snippet of code to create part of it. It could be something as simple as a missing parenthesis or space, or it could be that your SQL is simply incorrect, but without seeing it there's no way to know.

Comment: have you checked if dbLink.CurrentFirm.Id has the value you want

Comment: For starters, the last line should probably be `N_MSRS_{0} AS msr ON g.id = msr.id";` but there are probably greater problems than that.

Comment: is this query works in sql server management?

Comment: You should check out COALESCE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx Also check out unions. The point of using C# is that you can do one query, get the result and then do another one. Check your table design, and check your C# functionality. Never mind the syntax :)

Comment: yes the query runs in sql server management, and thanks for the N_MSRS_{0} AS msr ON g.id = msr.id it helped in sql management query but it still doesn't work in c#

Comment: Maybe he have N_GOODS_1, N_GOODS_2, N_GOODS_3 tables and number shows company code. Then formatting string is one way to go....but that means OP has terrible DB design.

Comment: Can you post exact query before executing it?

Comment: Oh thanks for that, yea I don't design my tables that way ha ha :P

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
return "SELECT * FROM ( " + sqlQueryString + " ) AS t";
```

Additionally you should try setting a breakpoint on your `return` statement. Get the value of `sqlQueryString` there and try running it directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 3):

First, this probably isn't a C# question except to say that you should likely learn the...

```
string strSql = @"SELECT * 
                   FROM TABLE";
```

syntax so that 1.) You can do away with all the `" +` stuff and 2.) You can cut and paste something in from an isql client.

So what you really want to do is...

1. Debug in your IDE by setting a breakpoint at that last line,
2. Hover your cursor over `sqlQueryString`,
3. Right-click `sqlQueryString` in the "floater" that appears (I put my mouse over `strReturn`, the floater comes up.  Right click the `strReturn` that appears floating above -- blue rectangle is what you want)

[image: floater from Visual Studio of a var]

4. Select the option to copy the *value*.
5. Paste your clipboard with `sqlQueryString`'s contents into Notepad, gvim, whatever.
6. **Let us know what that says.**
7. Then tell us [precisely what happens when you run that statement directly against the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1706257/1028230).

You might also give us some idea of what you expected to happen [based on having run the original query against the database earlier, perhaps].

And then accept that even the best of us occasionally lose an hour or two doing something dumb with SQL.  ;^)  With the above information, however, we could probably help cut that down a bit.

**EDIT:**  Rather, if, as your comment suggests, the query works when run directly against (MS-SQL Server?), the C# issue potentially comes *after* this code, when you run it against the database.  First do the above and ensure what's in sqlQueryString is what you ran against the db.

**EDIT2:** Made the debug steps into a bulleted list to make them more obvious.  Don't just tell us it work; tell us what was in `sqlQueryString`.  **But, again, as with the first edit, if that string is okay, your problem likely occurs later on in your C# code.**

Are you immediately throwing against the database?  What's that code look like?

Comment: Yes the code runs perfectly in MS-SQL Server, but when used in visual studio, everything ends there

Comment: No no, you have to tell us what was in `sqlQueryString`.  ;^)  Everything ends how?  Certainly the code doesn't bork in your snippet -- the string construction shouldn't cause an error.  Check those steps and try again, telling us what's in `sqlQueryString`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in the return statement at the end.

`( SELECT foo FROM bar ) AS baz;`  is not a valid SQL statement by itself, it's a fragment.

As @Yuck suggests, try `SELECT * FROM ( " + sqlQueryString + " ) AS t";` instead.